# How does the timeout setting for gunicorn works?

Tags: python, gunicorn

The documentation for gunicorn says the following about --timeout setting.
"Workers silent for more than this many seconds are killed and restarted."
What do we mean by silent here. What if our app does not get a request for 2 days. Would this initiate a worker shutdown? We have a flask app that serves only 5 users and those users might connect once a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in reality it actually kills the worker that received a request but hasn't completed within time period as provided by timeout parameter rather than one just waiting for work. Here's a stackoverflow question that i think may help:

[gunicorn doesn't kill worker even after timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54832771/gunicorn-doesnt-kill-worker-even-after-timeout)